# how to save a variable not removed by rm(list=ls())

Tags: r, environment-variables

I would like to save a variable in R, that would not be removed by `rm(list=ls())`

I think it is possible as for instance installed functions and data from packages are not removed.

Edit: One possibility could be to set an env variable just for this R session. I have tried `Sys.setenv(ENV_VAR = 1)` but `Sys.getenv(ENV_VAR)` returns an error.

(I am on windows 32bits, R 2.12.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, to get the environment variable you need to put quotes around it:

```
Sys.setenv(ENV_VAR = 1)
Sys.getenv("ENV_VAR")
```

Second, as Chase said, a new environment is the way to go - but you must also attach it:

```
e <- new.env()
e$foo <- 42
attach(e, name='myvars')
rm(list=ls()) # Remove all in global env
foo # Still there!
```

...and to detach it:

```
detach('myvars')
```

Comment: Mostly agreed, but I'm not convinced about the use of `attach`.  Try `with` instead.  http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/04/29/friday-function-triple-bill-with-vs-within-vs-transform/

Answer (score 4):

The proper answer involves putting your variable into a new environment. One quick and dirty trick is to prepend a `.` in front of the variable so that it isn't picked up by `ls()`.

```
> x <- 1:10
> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> .x <- x
> ls()
[1] "x"
> rm(list = ls())
> ls()
character(0)
> .x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the following:

```
# make busy workspace
x<-1
y<-2
z<-3

> ls()
[1] "x" "y" "z"

# determine what to keep
save<-"x"
#discard the rest
rm(list=ls()[!(ls()%in%save)])

> ls()
[1] "x"
```

Comment: good idea, but I don't have the control on that command. It is doing rm(list=ls()) and that's it